# How to clone Andengine files?

Tags: android, andengine

I have seen many tutorials which suggest cloning of andengine and its extensions by using Mercurial.

The url is https://code.google.com/p/andengine. However when I clone using this URL I get a single README file telling me that everything has moved to https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine

However I am not able to clone from here. How should I clone the files

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They moved to Github so you need to use [Git](http://git-scm.com/) to get the files. See [Installing Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git) for more info.

```
git clone git://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine.git
```

Comment: same basic answer I gave him in the first iteration of this question - apparently not what he wants to hear.  Tinniam, the code on google is the old, no longer supported version of AndEngine - you are much better off with the GitHub version

Comment: @jmr499485 - I did see your reply. I was hoping I would not not need to install using git. It looks like I will have to use it now.

Comment: If you don't need to work with it, to _just_ get the files you can use https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/archive/GLES2.zip